# Gallery with "stacking" images

Tags: html, css

I wan't to make an image gallery in CSS. The images mustn't be cropped but need to have the same width. I don't want them to be side be side but rather one on top of another. I've provided an image of what i want it to look like. The bottom part is a descripton for each image. The markup and CSS for now are something like this:

```
<div class="thumbnail">    
<a  title="img1" href="images/img1.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery1">
<img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="img1">
<p>img1</p>
</a>
</div>

<div class="thumbnail">    
<a  title="img2" href="images/img2.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery2">
<img src="images/img2.jpg" alt="img2">
<p>img2</p>
</a>
</div>


.thumbnail {
     width: 300px;
 }
```

[The layout i want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aczYV.png)
[This is what i have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPx9u.png)

Comment: You can't with pure css and html as far as I know. Have you looked at [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)?

Comment: Hey, this looks great.  I've been looking for something like this. Thanks. I'm just wondering what would happen with the images in case javascript is not enabled on the browser.

Comment: A lack of javascript will break the masonry layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I needed in pure CSS. So here's the link if anybody needs it.
https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
height: auto
```

using a layout like this to achieve your images scale as you like.

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .col{       
        width:300px;
        float:left;
        margin: 5px;
    }
    .col img{       
        width:100%;;
        height:auto;
    }
    </style>
<div class="col">
<img src="img0.png" />
<br/><br/>
<img src="img1.png"  />
</div>
<div class="col">
<img src="img0.png"  />
<br/><br/>
<img src="img1.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.